# R: read binary file of unsigned chars

Tags: r

I am trying to read a binary file of unsigned chars into R. The binary file is supposed to be storing integers 0 to 7 in unsigned char format but I am unable to get it. I have tried the following:

```
readBin(con = "tmp.out", what = "character", size = 1, n = 604*800)
```

But I get essentially gibberish.
I am aware that there are questions that are of a similar nature on StackOverflow but none of them seem to address exactly my question (or did not seem to). Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time.

Comment: I read esoteric formats into R quite a bit. Perhaps provide some sample data?

Comment: Happy to, but can you give me a clue as to how to provide the data (it is in the form of a binary file). Alternatively, is it possible to create an unsigned character binary file in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer that is:

```
 xx <- readBin(con = "tmp.out", what = "integer", n = 604 * 800, size = 1,  signed = F)
```

Basically, there is a signed option in the readBin function and a size option that should be set to 1 (byte).